# Griddb Nosql - Error when make Makefile:382 all-recursive

Tags: griddb

I implemented with the guideline from https://github.com/griddb/griddb_nosql

I had already run below command
./bootstrap.sh
./configure

But when I ran make command, I encounter the following error:

```
$ make
Making all in 3rd_party/MessagePack
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/conglb/Documents/github/griddb_nosql/3rd_party/MessagePack'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/conglb/Documents/github/griddb_nosql/3rd_party/MessagePack'
Making all in utility
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/conglb/Documents/github/griddb_nosql/utility'
source='./util/allocator.cpp' object='libutil_a-allocator.o' libtool=no \
DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../depcomp \
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"GridDB_NoSQL\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"griddb_nosql\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.3.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"GridDB_NoSQL\ 4.3.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"griddb_nosql\" -DVERSION=\"4.3.0\" -I.  -I../utility   -Wall -finput-charset=UTF-8 -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-function -std=gnu++0x -O3 -fno-tree-vectorize -DNDEBUG -c -o libutil_a-allocator.o `test -f './util/allocator.cpp' || echo './'`./util/allocator.cpp
../depcomp: line 772: exec: g++: not found
Makefile:382: recipe for target 'libutil_a-allocator.o' failed
make[1]: *** [libutil_a-allocator.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/conglb/Documents/github/griddb_nosql/utility'
Makefile:386: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anybody say what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your error is ../depcomp: line 772: exec: g++: not found.
- It causes by your environment which don't have g++ compiler.
- I checked on GridDB repository in Github. Compiler required is CentOS 7.6 (gcc 4.8.5), Ubuntu 18.04 (gcc 4.8.5) and openSUSE Leap 15.1 (gcc 4.8.5).
- You need to install g++ compiler version 4.8.5.